# request for member '****' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct list
{
    char sur[128];
    int  ball;
    int  mark;
}list;
int addstud(char *std,list *stud);

int main()
{
 list stud;
 char std[] = "stud.txt";
    addstud(std,&stud);
}

int addstud(char *std,list *stud)
{
    FILE *fl;
    fl  = fopen(std, "a");
    if (fl == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter Surname student: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*1[\n]", &(stud.sur));
    fprintf(fl, "%s", stud.sur);
    printf("Enter student scores:");
    scanf("%d", &(stud.ball));
    fprintf(fl, "%4d", stud.ball);
    stud.mark = 0;
    fprintf(fl,"%4d\n",stud.mark);
    fclose(fl);
    printf("The student's addition was successfully completed\n Press Enter for continue...");
    getch();
    system("cls");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы передаете в функцию *указатель* на `stud`:

```
int addstud(char *std,list *stud)
```

А обращаетесь так, как будто это объект структуры, а не указатель на него.

Обращаться к полям через указатель нужно с использованием `->`:

```
scanf("%d", &(stud->ball));
```

Comment: Вы же отвечали мне сегодня,`"%[^\n]%*1[\n]` - как это работает?

Comment: Считываем в переданный буфер все символы, кроме символа новой строки, после чего считываем один символ новой строки, никуда его не записывая (игнорируем его). См., например, [тут](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).